# How to make a regex for "data1,data2"?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to make a regex which matches patterns like:

```
data1,data2
data1
```

but not `data1&data2` or any other special character apart from `,`.
I have tried few like `flag_regex = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9].*,.*[a-zA-Z0-9]*");`

1 and 2 are two different strings, **this is not a CSV**.

My regex only matches the first pattern, not the second one.

I am doing this in JavaScript.

I am trying to do something like this.

```
var flag_regex = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9].*,.*[a-zA-Z0-9]*");
if(!flag_regex.test(string))
{
    log.error("wrong query format");
    return res.status(404).send({"message":"wrong query format"});
}
```

It should accept string as `data1,data2` or just `data1`.

Comment: Regex is *not* the way to parse a csv!

Comment: @Jamiec I know sir regex is not a way to parse csv, these are two different string.

Comment: [regex101](http://regex101.com) is your best friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex to

```
var flag_regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:,[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/;
```

If you only allow 1 comma, replace the last `*` (zero or more repetitions) with `?` (one or zero repetitions).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JhzwMV/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1 or more alphanum
- `(?:,[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `,` - comma
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1 or more alphanum
- `$` - end of string.